# A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

I'm just new in ReactJS and I have a problem. I can't solve it. It seems everything is all right, but still console puts me:

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have
>   returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import Pokemon from './Pokemon';

class PokemonList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      species: [],
      fetched: false,
      loading: false,
    };
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
      loading : true
    });
    fetch('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151').then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>{
      this.setState({
        species : res.results,
        loading : true,
        fetched : true
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {fetched, loading, species} = this.state;
    let content;
    //This if seems to be the problem
    if(fetched){
      content =
      <div className="pokemon--species--list">
        {species.map((pokemon,index) => <Pokemon key={pokemon.name} id={index+1} pokemon={pokemon}/>)}
      </div>;
    }
    else if(loading && !fetched){
        content = <p> Loading ...</p>;
    }
    else{
      content = <div/>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PokemonList;
```

Pokemon.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Pokemon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {pokemon, id} = this.props;
    return
      <div className="pokemon--spacies">
        <div className="pokemon--spacies--container">
          <div className="pokemon--spacies--sprite">
            <img src={`/public/sprites/${id}.png`} />
          </div>
          <div className="pokemon--spacies--name"> {pokemon.name }</div>
        </div>
      </div>;
  }
}

export default Pokemon;
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple statements in `render` and hence you need to surround that within `()` See the below snippet. Also the `(` must be on the same line as `return` otherwise it will be treated a `return` only which is basically returning nothing.

```js
class Pokemon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var content = <div></div>
    return (
      <div className="pokemon--spacies">
        <div className="pokemon--spacies--container">
          <div className="pokemon--spacies--sprite">
            {content}
          </div>
          <div className="pokemon--spacies--name"> Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Pokemon/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Problem is in the return statement in Pokemon component, Because when you use:

```
return
   <div>
     ...
   </div>
```

It will be treated as:

```
return ;    //Automatic semicolon insertion

<div>
   ...
</div>
```

And that means you are not returning a valid element.

Check this answer for more details about **[Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)**.

**Solutions:**

Wither wrap all the elements by `()` like this:

```
return (
 ....
)
```

or put the div in the same line of return, like this:

```
return <div>
   ...
       </div>
```

Use this part it will work:

```
class Pokemon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {pokemon, id} = this.props;
    return(
      <div className="pokemon--spacies">
        <div className="pokemon--spacies--container">
          <div className="pokemon--spacies--sprite">
            <img src={`/public/sprites/${id}.png`} />
          </div>
          <div className="pokemon--spacies--name"> {pokemon.name }</div>
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of the way that you are giving value to "content"

When you are setting a value some kind of "html" as a value, you have to use this syntax:

```
content = (<div/>);
```

try it and let me know if it works!

good luck!

Comment: This is not true for JSX.

Comment: I've just tried to add brackets to all if and else statements and there's still the same problem.

Comment: Why is not true? I mean, Im in a react project and this is how i encapsulate HTML code before print it in the return function...

If you can't do this:

const data = (<div>INFORMATION</div>);

return = (<div>{data}</div>); 

Tell me how would you do it?

Comment: In a return parenthesis are needed, not when setting a one-line variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ES6 syntax's make sure you do the following

```
const App = ()=> (
  <div>
        <p>Adam</p>
        <p>Alex</p>
  </div>
)
```

Here the "**()**" is important and it says the bracketed is the jsx returned

If you are having a single line return then you can do this

```
const App = ()=> <h1>Hello</h1>
```